# Is it possible to reference a value in the app.config file somewhere else in the same config file?

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, appsettings

A recent scenario got me thinking...

I have a key/value pair defining a certain setting in my appSettings section. Later on in the app.config file I have to set a value for an email logger, and I'd like to just use the value from the key/value pair defined in the appSettings section.

How can I do that? Or is it even possible?

Comment: Please show some the config markup code. You may just be able to remove the value from your appSettings and get it from the other configuration section.

Comment: Thanks João Angelo - that's what I wanted to know.